# Web Designer vs Visual identity creator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, identity

Is The main role of a web designer is to create a  full visual identity to a company through his design ? ( to a company that don't have a visual identity )

Answer (score 1):

No, the main role of a web designer is to design web sites. After all, that's likely why they were given the title of 'web designer'.

That doesn't mean they can't handle other design tasks, of course.